# Symfony2: Custom identifier in Sonata entities

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, uuid, symfony-sonata, sonata

I have an entity with a custom id (i.e. UUID) generated on __construct function.

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;
use Rhumsaa\Uuid\Uuid;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* @ORM\Entity
*/
class Person
{
    /**
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\Column(type="string")
    */
    private $id;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string")
    */
    private $name;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->id = Uuid::uuid4()->toString();
    }
```

This entity is used in sonata and also in other part of the project. I need this entity to have id before persisting and flushing it, so I can not use a an auto-increment.

So, the problem is sonata don't let me create entities because it takes the create option as and edit on executing because that entity already has an id, but this entity does not exists at this moment, so it fails.

The problem isn't the library for generating UUID, any value for 'id' fails.

Anyone know how to solve it? Another similar approach to solve the problem?

Comment: Can you show some code to clarify what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't set your id in the constructor, but rather use the `prePersist` Doctrine event to alter your entity before persisting it for the first time.

You may use annotations to do so, see [the Doctrine Documentation on prePersist](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-prepersist).

The issue with setting the id in the constructor is that you may override it when you're retrieving it from the database, in which case it will be incorrect.

Comment: That entity is also used in a non-sonata code and I need to have an ID before persisting it to the database. How to solve it?

Comment: Why do you need the ID before persisting it? To persist it only? In that case the prePersist will fill it in beforehand. Else, if it is to manage relations, I'd advise you retrieve the ID only once the entity is persisted.

Comment: For testing purposes. For instance, I have a service that logs de id: $this->logger->info("Person: ".$person->getId()); and I don't want to persist and flush that entity because it spends a lot of time and I don't want to inject the real entitymanager in that test, just a mock.

Comment: You mean you want to log the id before persisting it? Why don't you log another information about the entity then? The ID should be managed by the DBMS as much as possible.

Comment: That's not true. In doctrine constructor is only called once during first entity creation. Then all objects are initialized via proxy classes.